# Xcode returns nil on string that isn't optional

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, null

I have a function that takes an image and a string. When I try to put the string into a longer string using the () ability, it tells me it finds nil while unwrapping an optional. Exception it's not an optional at all, it's a string. I can print the value out and it comes out correctly.

```
func UpdateBusiness(logo: UIImage, category: String) {
        guard let bizID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: defaultKeys.businessID) else {return}
        let thisURL = "http://mywebsite.com/api/v0.1/Business/EditBusinessLogoAndCategory?businessID=\(bizID)&category=\(category)"
        let combinedURL = URL(string: thisURL)!
}
```

creating the URL crashes the system. I can see the value of category in the debugger, and I have no optionals in this string. How can it find nil?

Comment: Did you check what `bizID` is in the debugger?

Comment: Yes. It's coming in correctly, as well. thisURL works correctly when I don't add category in there.

Comment: Does it crash on the `let` line or another line?  I am sure there is more code than what you have shown, since the code shown doesn't do anything with `thisURL`.  My guess is that you are trying to create a `URL` from `thisURL` and *that* returns `nil`.

Comment: @Paulw11 it crashes on that line, specifically.  If I put it in a guard statement it returns immediately.

Comment: In your comment you said it crashes when you add `category`, but you don't check `category`.  Putting a `guard` around that `let` shouldn't have any affect since it isn't an optional.  Is it possible that what you are passing in to the `category` parameter is an implicitly unwrapped optional?  Please show more of your *actual* code since the code shown here can't crash in the way you are saying.

Comment: My apologizes. It crashes on the creating of the URL()

Comment: There you go. _This_ is the line that's crashing: `let combinedURL = URL(string: thisURL)!` And rightly so; this is not a valid URL. In general, _never_ call `URL(string:)`. Use URLComponents to form a valid URL and to catch any difficulties along the way.

Comment: How is that so? I've got several other function calls with URLs that are seemingly the same. What's wrong with this one? I figured my error was something simple, but after hours staring at it I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: We can't tell you why the url is invalid since we don't know the actual values of `bizID` and `category`, but it is unsafe to force unwrap the return value of `URL` since it can fail if the URL isn't well formed

Comment: So what is the correct way to form a URL to pass into a URLRequest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is crashing due to force unwrapping. In this case can recommend to use **URLComponents**.This is more readable than the string joining and for large number of parameter string joining is not a good option.

```
var components = URLComponents()
components.scheme = "http"
components.host = "mywebsite.com"
components.path = "/api/v0.1/Business/EditBusinessLogoAndCategory"
components.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "businessID", value: bizID),
    URLQueryItem(name: "category", value: category)

]
let url = components.url



enter code here
```